# List consisting of positions of the matrix elements and the elements themselves

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

Given a 2D matrix I would like to make a list with elements consisting of positions of the matrix elements and the elements themselves. Let the matrix be

```
mat = {{a, b, c}, {s, v, t}, {k, l, m}};
```

then the aim is to obtain this:

```
(*   {{1, 1, a}, {1, 2, b}, {1, 3, c}, {2, 1, s}, {2, 2, v}, {2, 3, t}, {3,
   1, k}, {3, 2, l}, {3, 3, m}} *)
```

The element `a` of the initial matrix has the list coordinates `{1,1}` and, therefore, is transformed into `{1,1,a}`, and so on. 
The solution is easy to obtain with the above matrix:

```
   Flatten[Map[{Position[mat, #], #} &, 
   mat, {2}] /. {{{a_, b_}}, c_} -> {a, b, c}, 1]

(*  {{1, 1, a}, {1, 2, b}, {1, 3, c}, {2, 1, s}, {2, 2, v}, {2, 3, t}, {3,
   1, k}, {3, 2, l}, {3, 3, m}}  *)
```

The problem with this solution arises in the case, when not all elements in the initial matrix are different.

Any idea?

PS. One can do, of course, straightforwardly:

```
Flatten[Table[{i, j, mat[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, Dimensions[mat][[1]]}, {j, 
   1, Dimensions[mat][[1]]}], 1]
```

but I am looking for a faster approach.

Comment: You could use `ParallelTable` with your second solution to speed it up quite a bit if you have multiple cores.

Comment: this is quite short and straightforward: `MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, mat, {2}]`. But what exactly would make you consider an approach "faster"?

Comment: @Albert Retey  You answer is in fact faster, if compared with my second solution.

Comment: Obfuscation frenzy: `Flatten /@ List @@@ ArrayRules@(SparseArray@mat) // Most`

Comment: On my computer the `Table`-solution is the fastest. Twice as fast than @AlbertRetey' s comment and slightly faster than @YvesKlett

Comment: Interesting that you mention that `MapIndexed` is faster. For me the table approach also seems to be slightly faster, at least if one keeps the `Sequence` for flattening the indices. For the `Table` approach I think you'd need `Dimensions[mat][[2]]` for the `j` loop counter for nonsquare matrices?

Comment: @@YvesKlett Yves, it is probably my illusion that Table is the slowest solution, and if to apply it to large array it is better to look for something else. Good to know that it is not always the case.

Comment: I added the `performance-tuning` tag, since you seemed to be asking for speed. Feel free to roll back, although I'm pretty sure some of our most expert *Mathematica* users monitor `performance-tuning`, so it's perhaps a good way to attract attention? :)

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch perhaps you can add some benchmarking examples, as this will probably be quite dependent on size, entry type etc..

Comment: I would have done @Albert's snippet as `MapIndexed[Append[#2, #1] &, mat, {2}]`.

Comment: @J.M.: good point, yours is not only slightly shorter but also somewhat faster (still slower than `Table` for me, though)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optimized `Table` wins, but in general setting `Array` is faster.

Array approach is inspired by the @LeonidShifrin [vintage comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764774/using-array-and-table-functions-in-mathematica-which-is-best-when#comment6602932_5764849).

This version is **fast and robust** for 2D. For more dimentions needs tuning.

```
Array[{#1, #2, mat[[#1, #2]]} &, Dimensions[mat]]
```

The following one looks **shortest and universal** but indeed **slow** (due to dual `Sequence` burden; note that use of only one `##` in any position does not diminish the speed seriously).

```
Array[{##, mat[[##]]} &, Dimensions[mat]]
```

For the small 2D problem at hand it is fine though:

```
mat = {{a, b, c}, {s, v, t}, {k, l, m}};
Flatten[Array[{##, mat[[##]]} &, {3, 3}], 1]
```

> `{{1, 1, a}, {1, 2, b}, {1, 3, c}, {2, 1, s}, {2, 2, v}, {2, 3, t}, {3, 1, k}, {3, 2, l}, {3, 3, m}}}`

`MapIndexed` approaches are also elegant but not that fast for long arrays and should as well be tuned a bit for multi-dimensional arrays.

**Addenum** Some timing comparisons:

Sample:

```
Clear[longMat];
longMat = RandomInteger[10, {1000, 1000}];
```

Optimized conditions (formula has exact size of matrix):

```
Table[{i, j, longMat[[i, j]]}, {i, 1000}, {j, 1000}]; // Timing
(* {0.078125, Null} *)

Array[{#1, #2, longMat[[#1, #2]]} &, {1000, 1000}]; // Timing
(* {0.09375, Null} *)

-----------------------------------

MapIndexed[Append[#2, #1] &, longMat, {2}]; // Timing
(* {1.0625, Null} *)

Array[{##, longMat[[##]]} &, {1000, 1000}]; // Timing
(* {1.625, Null} *)

MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, longMat, {2}]; // Timing
(* {1.96875, Null} *)
```

Unknown 2D Matrix:

```
Array[{#1, #2, longMat[[#1, #2]]} &, Dimensions[longMat]]; // Timing
(* {0.109375, Null} *)

Table[{i, j, longMat[[i, j]]}, {i, Dimensions[longMat][[1]]}, {j, 
    Dimensions[longMat][[2]]}]; // Timing
(* {0.96875, Null} *) ----> "much slower"

----------------------------------------

MapIndexed[Append[#2, #1] &, longMat, {Length[Dimensions[longMat]]}]; // Timing
(* {1.09375, Null} *)

Array[{##, longMat[[##]]} &, Dimensions[longMat]]; // Timing
(* {1.64063, Null} *)

MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, longMat, {Length[Dimensions[longMat]]}]; // Timing
(* {1.98438, Null} *)
```